# How to filter WordPress Result by category and tags?

Tags: wordpress, filter, tags

I have created a search form and search.php file to display the result. The only thing is that, I want to filter including the tags instead the content and titles only. Is there any wordpress function for this process?

Search Form Code:

```
<?php if(is_category(array('general-support','activities','discount-cards','equipment','financial','holidays','medical','respite')) || is_single()){?>

<div style="width:auto; margin:0px 40px 0px 20px;">

    <form role="search" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl');?>" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">

        <div>
            <h2>Search for</h2>
            <div><input type="text" name="s" id="s" style="width:100%; padding:5px; border:1px solid #ccc; box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px #f0f0f0;" /></div>
            <div><input type="hidden" value="14,16,21,18,20,15,22,19,17" name="cat" id="scat" /></div>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Search.php

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&showposts=10'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="entry">

        <!--start.entry-wrapper-->
        <div class="entry-wrapper">

            <!--start.post-thumbnail-->

            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){?>

            <div class="post-thumbnail-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb'); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>

            <!--end.post-thumbnail-->

            <!--start.post-entry--->
            <div class="post-enry-wrapper">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'udesign' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="postmetadata">
                    <?php the_content();?>              
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--end.post-entry-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--end.entry-wrapper-->

    </div>

    <?php if(!is_category() && !is_single()){?>

    <div><?php if(function_exists('kc_add_social_share')) kc_add_social_share(); ?></div>

    <?php }?>

</div>
<div class="addGap"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php       // Pagination
if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) :
    wp_pagenavi();
else : ?>

    <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link() ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link() ?></div>
</div>

<?php       endif; ?>
```

Please advise, I don't like to use any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming I understand your question, this should help:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

if you have multiple taxonomies (more than just tags) and wish to merge them into a single alpha sorted array, let me know. Somewhere I have a function that does that merge / sort.